# Jqplot to image bug

Tags: jqplot

I am using the default `jqplotToImageStr()` function to get the image data in the form of base64string of my charts.

The problem is that on the image the ticks, point labels and legend text is shifted right by about 50% of the image's width.

This is an example:

[image: Buggy chart]

Comment: Can you provide code to reproduce this?  Or better yet create a jsFiddle that recreates it?

Comment: What exactly would you like to see? Code rendering the chart or the code saving the image as `.png`?

Comment: The smallest example that reproduces the bug.  Preferably in the form of a jsFiddle.